# GCP DataFlow Streaming Piepeline - Apache beam Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am working on GCP Dataflow streaming pipeline development. There are different sites and assets of a plant according to business requirements.
At every 10 seconds in my pipeline code, my fixed window function of Apache beam gets the payload from Pubsub and reads the data.

I want to process the data which contains parameters: `RUNNING_STATE, ACCELERATION_STATE` of a motor used in PLC on client site.
Note: `RUNNING_STATE` could be 1 or 0 which means motor is running or stop.

Each time I process a row using `ParDO` function, my element gets the payload.

Problem comes when:
Parameter_name: `ACCELERATION_STATE` comes but the `RUNNING_STATE` for a particular asset is not known from the past for the particular asset. How to initialize it ?

I have tried using it in a state of a class variable with a dictionary:

```
{'ACCELERATION_STATE': 20, ''RUNNING_STATE': 1, 'asset': 'xyz', 'site': 1}
```

It is now getting difficult to maintain states for each assets and site in memory of beam or class in python in the dataflow job as for each sites there are 10,00,000 or more of assets and there could be many sites as well.

How to do this and what could be the work around for this ?

I have tried using it in a state of a class variable with a dictionary:

```
{'ACCELERATION_STATE': 20, ''RUNNING_STATE': 1, 'asset': 'xyz', 'site': 1}
```

Instead of writing it into a separate bigquery table, I would want to reduce the cost and keep it inside memory or if it could be done in some other way..

Comment: Please use universal measurements instead of local words like *crore* that most of the world does not use or understand.